# I want to get only next 5 words after my character is matched

Tags: c#, regex

I am using `Regex` in C#. I want to get next 5 words after my string has been matched.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("Born(.*){0,5}");
string result = regex.Match(UrlString).Value;
```

First of all I need to to find the word "Born". Then I need to get next 5 words after the word "Born" has been found.

#### Example

Input:

> Example-Born to a Gujarati family in Vadnagar, Modi helped his father sell tea as a child and later ran his own stall.

Result:

> to a Gujarati family in

But i am not getting the desired result.

Comment: Test case please?

Comment: Please define 'word'

Comment: Do you mean "characters", not "words"?

Comment: _But i am not getting the desired result._ what result _are_ you getting? What result _did_ you expect? Provide a short example with what you are actually getting and what you actually expected.

Comment: First fall i need to to find the word "Born". Then i need to get next 300 characters after the word  "Born" has been found.

Comment: @ParthPandita simply restating your problem statement doesn't provide us any additional information. People have asked you questions already, can you address those?

Comment: Not the best question I read, but pretty clear what he was asking, ***before somebody messed*** up his text by editing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Regex r = new Regex("Born (?<words>([^ ]+ ){5})");
string input = "asd Born asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd Born qwe qwe qwe qwe qwe rtz rtz rtz";

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["words"].Value);
}
```

Explaination:

```
(?<words>xxxxxx) // is a group which can be accessed from Matches
[^ ] // All characters except space " "
+ // one or more times
([^ ]+ ) // characters followed by a space => A word
{5} // five words
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string result = UrlString.Substring(UrlString.IndexOf("Born"), 300);
```

with regex:

```
string result = Regex.Match(UrlString,@"Born(.){300}").ToString())
```

Comment: i need to use regex.

Comment: [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_)  take a length as second argument not index. Also this can throw ArgumentOutOfRange